# How do i make matplotlib only display the last graph?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I copied some code from a website because i'm too new to python to understand matplotlib and pandas but i needed something to simulate markov chains and visualize them. The problem is the code displays every graph for every iteration of the markov chain and i have no idea how to only make it display the last graph.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from random import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
P = np.array([[0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
              [0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
              [0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25],
              [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25],
              [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])

state=np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])
stateHist=state
dfStateHist=pd.DataFrame(state)
distr_hist = [[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]

for x in range(50):
    state=np.dot(state,P)
    print(state)
    stateHist=np.append(stateHist,state,axis=0)
    dfDistrHist = pd.DataFrame(stateHist)
    dfDistrHist.plot()

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are plotting in each iteration in the for loop.

Working code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from random import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

P = np.array([[0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0],
              [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
              [0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25],
              [0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25],
              [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25],
              [0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])

state=np.array([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]])
stateHist=state

for x in range(50):
    state=np.dot(state,P)
    stateHist=np.append(stateHist,state,axis=0)

dfDistrHist = pd.DataFrame(stateHist)
dfDistrHist.plot()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: out]